# Django: Assigning variables in template

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I assign a variable inside the django templating system ?

Assuming `Restaurant` is a Model:

`{% restaurant_id as restaurant.id %}` or `{{ restaurant_id as restaurant.id }}` are not working.

Answer (score 85):

You could use the [with template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with), and assign an internal template variable like this:

```
{% with restaurant_id=restaurant.id %}
... use restaurant_id in this template section ...
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 21):

Note: You can use filters within the "with" template tag:

```
foo is {{ foo }}
{% with bar=foo|slice'6:9' %}
  bar is {{ bar }}
{% endwith %}
```