# How to declare variables inside Django templates

Tags: django

How do I declare a variable in Django 1.8 Templates for example like this:

```
{% my_var = "My String" %}
```

And so that I can access it like this:

```
<h1>{% trans my_var %}</h1>
```

***Edit:***

**To demonstrate my purpose of this, this is my code:**

```
{% my_var = "String Text" %}

{% block meta_title %}{% trans my_var %}{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb_menu %}
{{ block.super }}
<li>{% trans my_var %}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<h1>{% trans my_var %}</h1>
```

Comment: Better yet... what are you trying to do with it first? some template tags can assign to a variable but it depends what you're doing

Comment: @Sayse I am trying to avoiding DRY. Is there a better way? I added more of my source code above.

Comment: Why can't you pass this string from the view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Assigning variables in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517933/django-assigning-variables-in-template)

Answer (score 21):

Try using the with tag.

```
{% with my_var="my string" %}
{% endwith %}
```

The other answer is more correct for what you're trying to do, but this is better for more generic cases.

Those who come here solely from the question title will need this.

Comment: You can also set multiple variables as in `{% with alpha=1 beta=2 %} (stuff to render){% endwith %}`

source: django docs -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Answer (score 20):

One way I like to use is:

```
{% firstof "variable contents" as variable %}
```

Then you use it as `{{variable}}` wherever you want without the necessity for nesting `with` blocks, even if you define several variables.

Answer (score 11):

You can assign the translation to a variable which you can use throughout.

```
 {% trans "my string" as my_var %}
 {{ my_var }}   {# You can use my_var throughout now #}
```

[Documentation for `trans` tag which is an alias for `translate` tag, after Django-3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag)

---

Full example with your code snippet

```
{% trans "String text" as my_var %}

{% block meta_title %}{{ my_var }}{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb_menu %}
{{ block.super }}
<li>{{ my_var }}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<h1>{{ my_var }}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Sayse! For some reason that didn't work though. Do I have to load anything specifically? Add something else to my code? I have loaded this at the moment: `{% load i18n mezzanine_tags %}`

Comment: @Y7da -  What does "didnt work" mean? any errors? Nothing extra other than what is needed for the django `trans` tag is needed, I dont know what effect mezzanine would have

Comment: No output at all. Just blank on the screen and nothing in the title.

Comment: @Y7da - You sure you're definitely using the tags as shown in my example? You can see the documentation using the same as above in the link I've provided

Comment: 100% sure. Looked at the documentation and it's all correct. I will investigate if there's a problem with Mezzanine that I using.