# Assign a value to a variable already declared in the template in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-template-filters, django-custom-tags

I googled but unable to find the solution. Where I went thought some answers like [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710043/how-to-declare-variables-inside-django-templates/34710719)

 Some official docs which I went through [Trans Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) [Built-In Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

### Template View

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

---

```
{% for each in content %}
  {% with tempID='' %} # It is initially empty string
    {% if each.contentID != tempID %}
      {% tempID = each.contentID %} # Want to assign new value to tempID
        ....
         ..
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any method to assign with tag variable. I tried custom_tags filters also. Not worked.

[image: I don't want to repeat ID Name]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to assign with tag variable?

Yes, you can simply use the `{% with tempID= each.contentID  %}` which in this case will assign a new value to the variable.

**Alternative**

Variables in templates are merely used to display values and are not often used in a way in which calculation or reassignment is performed. In such cases though you can solve it by using a [Django custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/). See the example below.

`.py` file - Assign a value to a variable

```
@register.filter(name='update_variable')
def update_variable(value):
    data = value
    return data
```

`.HTML` file

```
{% with "true" as data %}
    {% if data == "true" %}
        //do somethings
        {{update_variable|value_that_you_want}}
    {% else %}
        //do somethings
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Note that when you are using `Django filters` the variable instance resides in `Python` and not directly in the `Template`.

Comment: I tried this solution before but not worked! As I attached link.You didn't get the question I don't want to return value I want to store for the future purpose of checking as in your case return returns the value that stored in data. But I want to store in the template variable of with tag

Comment: By the way, Can I use tempID variable that I defined before and using same with tag again does that recall the variable that defined earlier or just define new one?

Comment: Ahh... in such case filters would be good. Just store it as a global variable and then u can use it to check-in the cases u want. As for the second question, I believe it overwrites it and so calls the defined new one

Comment: To expand, if u want to go with the filters method then define a kind of setter and getter methods in which the latter returns it while the former will not. Look into the custom filter tags, you will find a solution

Comment: See I added but it's not overwriting. I added Image that I don't want to repeat the name ID for each image in for loop

Comment: If you wish you can add a  `{% with tempID2 = each.contentID %} ` inside the if condition and on each instance of the loop check that the `tempid` and `tempID2` are not the same before setting the name att for the image.